# How to setup a control with month names

Tags: amazon-quicksight

In my db i have a column created_at (date_time format). I would like to create an analytical dashboard when it will be possible to filter data by create_at by giving month name (one or more - multiple choice)

I have added a new calculated field "month" in data set with following formula:

`formatDate(truncDate("MM",{created_at}),"MM" )`

As a result i get new column with strings like "01", "02" etc.

I've created a new parameter:
name: Month
Data type: string
Values: multiple values: {01, 02, 03 ....}

I've created a new control:
name: Month
Style: Multi select drop down
Values: Link to a data set field -> Data set -> Month column

I've created a new filter for Month columns, based on  Month parameter

My problem is: how to achieve the same result (filtering by month, multi select) having month names displayed in the control, not "01", "02" etc. Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

It is much better to have following formula in Month calculated field:

`extract("MM",{create_at})`

But it does not solve my problem....

Answer (score 4):

What i did, but i really don't like this solution as it is so ugly.....Any better solution is welcome :)

- new calculated field month_number, with formula:

  extract("MM",{create_at})
- new calculated field month_name with formula:

  ifelse({Month_number}=1,"Jan",ifelse({Month_number}=2,"Feb",ifelse({Month_number}=3, "Mar",ifelse({Month_number}=4, "Apr",ifelse({Month_number}=5, "May",ifelse({Month_number}=6, "Jun",ifelse({Month_number}=7, "Jul",ifelse({Month_number}=8, "Aug",ifelse({Month_number}=9, "Sep",ifelse({Month_number}=10, "Oct",ifelse({Month_number}=11, "Nov",ifelse({Month_number}=12, "Dec","Error"))))))))))))